# What is so weird about it?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I was going to a place for some summer school (in winter :)). But when I first landed at the airport, to attend the school, I just took a random picture, for the memory. However, I later realized something weird in it.

The story, although true, has nothing to do with the picture.

**Do you also notice weird thing in the picture?**

[image]
To make things more clear,  [this is a famous place](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corsica). This is picture of [Ajaccio Napoleon Bonaparte Airport](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajaccio_Napoleon_Bonaparte_Airport). May you find it helpful. It is a very touristic place.

Hint 1:

> Consult the image very carefully (you may have missed something). Don't overlook the obvious. You may find it helpful to start it again from the beginning to the end.

Hint 2:

> Look for living things.

Comment: Is the tag appropriate? Puzzle-identification is for questions about types of puzzles that you aren't sure about. If this is just supposed to be something we figure out ourselves, the enigmatic tag would be much more appropriate!

Comment: @n_palum thanks for the point. There is something puzzling or offside there. So, I thought of using that. Not very familiar with the terminologies. Feel free to ask any doubts

Comment: I'm not actually sure there's a puzzle here if it's just about finding something subjectively awkward in a random photo.

Comment: To the people who downvoted, please let me know the reason. So that I can improve and learn from the mistake(s).

Comment: I did not, but I think @IanMacDonald has stated what those people who downvoted are thinking. This puzzle is not designed to make one think, but rather to try to figure out what you think is odd in a picture that (as it turns out) isn't really that odd. This is as close to "what has it got in its pocketses" as you can get. There's really no fun to deriving the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the puzzling thing in this image is:

> The man in white pants and black jacket has no luggage. This is (presumably) puzzling because most people fly with some belongings.

Comment: Well done. Nothing more to say. That is what I was telling about the Touristic Place(Hint 1).

Comment: Thank you. The points are nice, but I would hesitate to call it weird or puzzling simply because an easy and normal explanation exists: he checked his bag and will entertain himself with his headphones on this flight.

Comment: And another: he is travelling with someone else (maybe the person a few steps behind him), and they have the luggage. And another: he is on (or returning from) a super-short trip and didn't need to bring any luggage.

Comment: I would agree that this is not weird at all as I am a person that travels without luggage very often

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to state the obvious:

> It's a blazing hot day, and several people are wearing thick heavy coats.

Comment: It is a good observation but still missing the answer.

Comment: 'It's a _______ ___ day' [spoilers covered with underscores] - how do you know?

Comment: the sun's out (shadows), no clouds $\implies$ no wind

Comment: To make things clear. I mentioned in the text it was in winter, so we can have sunny but not necessarily hot blazing :) Jackets are as a result of winter, that is why not an answer.

Comment: That's not unusual to see at airports, depending on where the plane has come from.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Added another answer

Based on what you said about look for living things I want to guess on:

> The guy standing in door A, that you can only see the security vest on

Another obvious thing

> That  "parkingsquare" or whatever it is where the painter didn't know how to pause the machine so he just did all the lines in one go

Answer (score 4):

> It looks like the tree in front of the airport plate is floating(between the man with white pants and the other man with black jacket). I don´t know if this is what we are looking for or this leads to something else.